# How to set the from 'day' and 'month' in datepickerfield in sencha touch 2

Tags: datepicker, sencha-touch-2, picker

I am trying to do something which I think should be simple enough. I am using a `datepickerfield` in ST2.1 and trying to set the start date. I know I can set the year like so:

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    picker: {
        yearFrom: newDate().getFullYear(),
        yearTo: 1930
    }
}
```

but I also want to be able to set the start day and month. Is this possible? The above produces a result like 'January 1, 2013' and that is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to set the initial date the picker comes up with, then you just want the `value` config attribute of the picker.

```
{
  xtype: 'datepickerfield',
  value: (new Date()), // the value in the actual input (will also be in the picker UI)
  picker: {
    value: (new Date()), // use this if you DON'T want/have a value in the actual input
    yearFrom: (new Date()).getFullYear(),
    yearTo: 1930
  }
}
```

Read more in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.field.DatePicker) (especially the "value" and "picker" config options). And here'a a [Sencha Fiddle](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/TNrZu/) demonstrating usage.

Answer (score -1):

You can create `monthFrom`,`monthTo` and `dayFrom`,`dayTo` configs. But for that you need to extend [Ext.picker.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/source/Date2.html#Ext-picker-Date). Create appropriate configs for those field and change `createSlots` method to limit month and day values.

In response to your comment, you can have reorder slots with `slotOrder` config in picker. Like -

`slotOrder:['day', 'month', 'year']`

Once you extend `Ext.picker.Date` you can modify certain slot as you want and then can have full day name in first slot.

Comment: That would actually set the value of the datepickerfield. What I am looking for is a way to set the `picker` start date with full day, month, year values so that the picker brings up the current date when the user opens it up.